# Fatty belly for my zebra danio - what should I do? I don't think she is pregnant

Tags: health, aquarium, fish

I have another and she also have the same fatty belly:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've had a problem with my Danio too. I determined that she just ate too much and was bloated. I recommend decreasing food and seeing what happens before jumping to conclusions of a deadly disease. But I do recommend separating your Danio just in case and decreasing food.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for the replies... It was just the excess food... As they usually all the food even which is for others. I started giving the the food once in a day for a week and made sure other are also able to eat by blocking these two and now they are fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have raised zebras and , mostly, giant danios ; that is too large for eggs . My guess would be disease "dropsy". What I would do is wait for them to die and make sure no other fish also have the problem. Dropsy does not seem to be very contagious.